# ExpandableListView with Checkboxes at two levels in android?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

Hello I am working with expendableListView in android extending BaseExpandableListAdapter in  Build Parent and child xml files 
                    main.xml- placed expendableListview
                    group_item- placed one checkbox
                    child_item - put one checkbox
                    Here is the code I tried the code of Adapter
            I fetched all child's data but not able to set that data and display in onclick of parent row. I tried a lot but getting NullPointerException for childdatalist. Here is the code I tried for my this many of files.

**CategoryBaseAdapter.java**

```
 public class CategoryBaseAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter  {              
private Context mContext;        
private HashMap<String, List<ProfessionChildEntity>> mListDataChild;                     private ArrayList<ProfessionEntity> mListDataGroup;
   private HashMap<Integer, boolean[]> mChildCheckStates;           
    private ChildViewHolder childViewHolder;
            private GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder;
            private String groupText;

            private String childText; 
     public CategoryBaseAdapter(Activity context,ArrayList<ProfessionEntity>listDataGroup, HashMap<String, List<ProfessionChildEntity>> listDataChild) {

 mContext = context;

 mListDataGroup = listDataGroup;
 mListDataChild = listDataChild;

 mChildCheckStates = new HashMap<Integer, boolean[]>();}

                    @Override
                    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getGroupCount() {
                        return mListDataGroup.size();
                    }

                    /*  
                     * This defaults to "public object getGroup" if you auto import the methods
                     * I've always make a point to change it from "object" to whatever item
                     * I passed through the constructor
                    */ 
                    @Override
                    public ProfessionEntity getGroup(int groupPosition) {
                        return mListDataGroup.get(groupPosition);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
                        return groupPosition;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                        groupText = getGroup(groupPosition).getDecription();
                        if (convertView == null) {
                            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext                                 .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);

                                groupViewHolder = new GroupViewHolder();
        groupViewHolder.mGroupText = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupTextView);

                            convertView.setTag(groupViewHolder);
                        } else {

                            groupViewHolder = (GroupViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                        }

                        groupViewHolder.mGroupText.setText(groupText);

                        return convertView;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
                        return mListDataChild.get(mListDataGroup.get(groupPosition).getUsesr_type()).size();
                    }

                    @Override
        public ProfessionChildEntity getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {                   return mListDataChild.get(mListDataGroup.get(groupPosition).getDecription()).get(childPosition);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                        return childPosition;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                        final int mGroupPosition = groupPosition;
                        final int mChildPosition = childPosition;

                        childText = getChild(mGroupPosition, mChildPosition).getDescription();

                        if (convertView == null) {

                            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);

                            childViewHolder = new ChildViewHolder();

                            childViewHolder.mChildText = (TextView) convertView
                                    .findViewById(R.id.childTextView);

                            childViewHolder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

                            convertView.setTag(R.layout.child_item, childViewHolder);

                        } else {

                            childViewHolder = (ChildViewHolder) convertView
                                    .getTag(R.layout.child_item);
                        }

                        childViewHolder.mChildText.setText(childText);
                        childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

                        if (mChildCheckStates.containsKey(mGroupPosition)) {

                            boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);                           childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(getChecked[mChildPosition]);
                } else {
                            boolean getChecked[] = new boolean[getChildrenCount(mGroupPosition)];
                        mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);
              childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                        }

                        childViewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                                if (isChecked) {

                                    boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);
                getChecked[mChildPosition] = isChecked;
                    mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);

                                } else {

                boolean getChecked[] = mChildCheckStates.get(mGroupPosition);
                            getChecked[mChildPosition] = isChecked;
                            mChildCheckStates.put(mGroupPosition, getChecked);
                }
               }
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

}
});              return convertView;}   @Override public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                return true;
                }
                @Override
                public boolean hasStableIds() {
                    return true;
                }   
                public final class GroupViewHolder {
                    CheckBox mGroupText;
               }
               public final class ChildViewHolder     
               TextView mChildText;
                CheckBox mCheckBox;
       }        
    }
```

The Other file is my activity file i am trying to get data from SQLITEdatabase.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class Signup_catgegory2 extends Activity {
                ExpandableListView listView1;
                ArrayList<ProfessionEntity> listProfession = new ArrayList<ProfessionEntity>();
                List<ProfessionChildEntity> listChildProfession=new ArrayList<ProfessionChildEntity>();
                DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;
                String typeOfUser;
                HashMap<String, List<ProfessionChildEntity>> listDataChild;
                Context context = null;
                CategoryBaseAdapter adapter;
                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup_category);
                    listView1=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                    InitDatabase();
                    Intent in = getIntent();
                    typeOfUser = in.getStringExtra("typeOfUser");
                    loadProfessionData(typeOfUser);
                    /*listChild.put("parent_key",listChildProfession);
                    listDataChild.add(listChild);*/
                    adapter=new CategoryBaseAdapter(Signup_catgegory2.this, listProfession,listDataChild);
                    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                private void loadProfessionData(String pos) {
                    listProfession = databaseHandler.getParentCategory(typeOfUser);
                    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < listProfession.size(); i++) {
                        Log.d("prfoession:", listProfession.get(i).getDecription());
                        list.add("" + listProfession.get(i).getDecription());
                        loadChildProfessionData(i);
                    }

                }
                private void loadChildProfessionData(int pos) {
                    listChildProfession = databaseHandler.getPChildCategory(pos);
                    String parent_key=String.valueOf(pos);
                    List<ProfessionChildEntity> list = new ArrayList<ProfessionChildEntity>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < listChildProfession.size(); i++) {
                        //for(int j=0;j<listChildProfession.size();j++){
                        Log.d("prfoession:", listChildProfession.get(i).getDescription());
                        list.add(listChildProfession.get(i).getDescription());
                    //}

                    }
                    listDataChild.put(parent_key,list);
                }
                private void InitDatabase() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try {
                        databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(Signup_catgegory2.this);
                        databaseHandler.createdatabase();

                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
                    }
                    try {
                        databaseHandler.opendatabase();
                    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                        throw sqle;
                    }
                }
            }
```

ParentEntity and ChildEntity classes  database function to fetch up child's data.

**Database.java**

```
public ArrayList<ProfessionChildEntity> getPChildCategory(int Parent_key){
       ArrayList<ProfessionChildEntity> flashcardentity=new ArrayList<ProfessionChildEntity>();
       String selectQuery="SELECT * FROM "+"Child WHERE Parent_key ="+"'"+Parent_key+"'";
       Log.d("selectQuery",selectQuery);
       Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
       Log.d("Cusorfav","c"+cursor.getCount()+""+selectQuery);
       if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
              Log.d("cursorfav", "cinside");
              ProfessionChildEntity pce=new ProfessionChildEntity();
              pce.setUser_type(cursor.getString(0));
              pce.setChild_key(cursor.getInt(2));
              pce.setDescription(cursor.getString(3));
              flashcardentity.add(pce);
             }while(cursor.moveToNext());
             }

        return flashcardentity;

}
```

Comment: everything is right just to change in checkbox:focusable=false